# How can i call another activity from a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview

i have gridview in my app. and i have 6 items in it. i want call another actvity when click item. how can i do it? here is my code. help me pls.
now when i click item i can show message with toast. but i want run another activity help me pls.

```
public class GridViewImageTextActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView androidGridView;

    String[] gridViewString = {
            "Hesapla", "Geçmiş", "Paylaş", "Geribildirim", "Sıralama", "Beğen",


    } ;
    int[] gridViewImageId = {
            R.drawable.hesap, R.drawable.gecmis, R.drawable.paylas, R.drawable.geribildirim, R.drawable.siralama, R.drawable.begen


    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_view_image_text);

        CustomGridViewActivity adapterViewAndroid = new CustomGridViewActivity(GridViewImageTextActivity.this, gridViewString, gridViewImageId);
        androidGridView=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_view_image_text);
        androidGridView.setAdapter(adapterViewAndroid);
        androidGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int i, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(GridViewImageTextActivity.this, "GridView Item: " + gridViewString[+i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: When you click on an item in the grid view, Start your activity that  you want to show for the item clicked

'Intent intent = new Intent (GridViewImageTextActivity.this , NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create class of another activity, add this activity to `AndroidManifest.xml` file and start like this:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
    Context context = GridViewImageTextActivity.this;
    Intent intent = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                intent = new Intent(context, FirstActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return;
            case 1:
                intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return;
            case 2:
                // start another activity
                return;
            // and so on
        }
}
```

Comment: i have 6 grid items and i want each of items run activity. how can i do?

Comment: @AhmetÖzcan each of items run  different activity?

Comment: yes for example when i click first item i want first activity. second item another activity. third item other activity

Comment: you have to use switch

Comment: how can i do this help me pls

Comment: a lot of thnx for your reply. i trying now and i reply to you. thnx again

Comment: in line 
case 1:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return;
it say to me "intent already defined"

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: replace context with GridViewImageTextActivity .this

Comment: @AhmetÖzcan Have you pasted all my code? It must run

Answer (score 0):

1. First Create 6 Activities and their layouts for each activity.
2. Assign ids to each 6 items like button1,button2,button3 and so on
3. Replace Toast message line this Switch Case Statement
4. Here is sample code for first 3 items

   ```
   swithc(View v){case R.id.button1:startActivity(new Intent(GridViewImageTextActivity.this,ActivityB.clsss));break;case R.id.button2:startActivity(new Intent(GridViewImageTextActivity.this,ActivityC.clsss));break;case R.id.button3:startActivity(new Intent(GridViewImageTextActivity.this,ActivityD.clsss));break;}
   ```